# Бот не расшифровывает данные с Json формата

Tags: java, json, telegram-bot

```
public class Exchanger {
    //dbb05023d4e92e3b35fb5b735a3ec0015cc348e0/
    public static String getExchanger(String message, Model model ) throws IOException {
        URL url =new URL("http://api.minfin.com.ua/nbu/dbb05023d4e92e3b35fb5b735a3ec0015cc348e0/");
        Scanner in =new Scanner((InputStream)url.getContent());
        String result = "";
        while (in.hasNext()){
            result += in.nextLine();
        }

        //  JSONObject object=new JSONObject(result);
    //   model.setKey(object.getString("key"));


        JSONObject usd = new JSONObject(result);
        model.setKey(usd.getString("key"));
        model.setBib(usd.getDouble("bib"));
        model.setAsk(usd.getDouble("ask"));

        return   "key"+model.getKey()+"\n"+
                "bib"+model.getBib(0.0)+"\n"+
               "ask"+model.getAsk(0.0);
//return result;


    }
}
```

Comment: Бот должен выводить информацию о конвертации валют он получает данные в json формате в таком виде он может выводить,
нужно чтобы он их расшифровывал

Comment: добавьте комментарий (и комментарии) в вопросу, уберите лишние строки. Вы должны сначала прочитать объект валюты, а уже потом ображаться к  `bib` или `ask`. Посмотрите в браузере, как выглядит ваш JSON. И проверьте, что `result` овпадает с тем, что должно приходить.

Comment: если возвращать просто result  то оно выходит такой же формат который открывается в браузере

Comment: и если розкоментваты эти строки оно также не работает  JSONObject object=new JSONObject(result);
     model.setKey(object.getString("key"));

Answer (score 0):

Все просто :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Exchanger {

    private final static String MINFIN_URL = "http://api.minfin.com.ua/nbu/dbb05023d4e92e3b35fb5b735a3ec0015cc348e0/";

    public static List<Model> getExchanger() throws IOException {
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new URL(MINFIN_URL).openStream()).useDelimiter("\\A")) {
            final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "");
            return StreamSupport.stream(jsonObject.names().spliterator(), false)
                    .map((c) -> {
                        final JSONObject obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject((String) c);
                        return new Model(obj.getString("currency"), obj.getDouble("ask"), obj.getDouble("bid"));
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

}

class Model {

    private final Currency key;
    private final Double ask;
    private final Double bid;

    public Model(String key, Double ask, Double bid) {
        this.key = Currency.currencyFromString(key);
        this.ask = ask;
        this.bid = bid;
    }

    public Currency getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public Double getAsk() {
        return ask;
    }

    public Double getBid() {
        return bid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model{" + "key=" + key + ", ask=" + ask + ", bid=" + bid + '}';
    }

}

public enum Currency {

    EUR,USD,RUB;

    public static Currency currencyFromString(String currencyName){
        return java.util.Arrays.stream(Currency.values())
                .filter(currency->currency.name().equalsIgnoreCase(currencyName))
                .findAny().orElseThrow(UnsupportedOperationException::new);
    }
}



import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Exchanger {

    //dbb05023d4e92e3b35fb5b735a3ec0015cc348e0/
    public static String getExchanger(String message, Model model) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://api.minfin.com.ua/nbu/dbb05023d4e92e3b35fb5b735a3ec0015cc348e0/");
        Scanner in = new Scanner((InputStream) url.getContent());
        String result = "";
        while (in.hasNext()) result += in.nextLine();

        System.out.println(result);

        JSONObject object=new JSONObject(result);

        JSONObject usd =  object.getJSONObject("usd");
        model.setKey(usd.getString("currency"));
        model.setBib(usd.getDouble("bid"));
        model.setAsk(usd.getDouble("ask"));

        JSONObject eur=object.getJSONObject("eur");
        model.setKey(eur.getString("currency"));
        model.setBib(eur.getDouble("bid"));
        model.setAsk(eur.getDouble("ask"));


        JSONObject rub =object.getJSONObject("rub");
        model.setKey(rub.getString("currency"));
        model.setBib(rub.getDouble("bid"));
        model.setAsk(rub.getDouble("ask"));


        return usd.getString("currency")+
                usd.getDouble("bid")+
                usd.getDouble("ask")+

                eur.getString("currency")+
                eur.getDouble("bid")+
                eur.getDouble("ask")+

                rub.getString("currency")+
                rub.getDouble("bid")+
                rub.getDouble("ask");


    }
}
```

Comment: не знаю почему но ничего не изменилось
информацию не выводит

Comment: @Max Bahnuik простите, куда не выводит? код протестирован, все работает. как вы запускаете данный код? какие у вас зависимости подключены к проекту?

Comment: Простите я перезапустил код все работает но суть моего вопроса была в том почему в моем коде это не работало. Простой Json формат оно возвращает

Comment: @Max Bahnuik потому что вы его парсите неправильно. вы получаете JSONObject  и у него запрашиваете все данные, а на самом деле у вас в объекта типа JSONObject  приходят данные в виде коллекции типа ключ-значение,ключ действително key и это наименование валюты,а вот объект-это фактически еще один JSONObject,где уже есть ask,bid ит.д. у первого JSONObject всю информацию получить нельзя. надо получить сначала список ключей (наименования валют),а уже потом проходить итератором и собирать всю информацию по каждой валюте. сейчас у вас есть рабочий код и ваш код. просто сравните логику -все поймете

Comment: я постарался сделать так как вы говорили но у меня не вийшо я немного перобив код по вашим рекомдациям и залил на файлообменника вот Сылка https://fex.net/uk/s/lkelz5e можете посмотреть что не так заранее спасибо

Comment: @Max Bahnuik код откорректировал и добавил исправленный в ответ. посмотрите внимательно JSON. вы у каждой валюты вызываете model.setKey(rub.getString("key")), а нужно model.setKey(usd.getString("currency")); в этом случае ваш код начнет работать, но не станет лучше. вы передаете в метод message и не используете его, объект model, согласно GRASP, должен создаваться там и в тот момент, когда он нужен, т.е. в методе getExchanger и вернуть этот метод должен именно модель, а уже сама модель должна знать , как отображаться в виде строки. каст - нехорошо, поэтому есть url.openStream(). и.т.д.